# How to include recieved token into a url wordpress

Tags: html, authentication, httprequest, token

Ive made this very simple form:

```
<form action="http://xxxxxx.xxx/GetLoginToken.ashx?userName=USERNAME&amp;password=PASSWORD" method="get" name="HentToken" target="_blank">
Username:<input name="USERNAME" type="text" />Password: <input name="PASSWORD" type="text" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

It then returns a "token", or 20 digits, to my browser, and writes it in the browser.

Is there any way I can make it so that the token is included in a URL, and then open that URL instead of just writing the token to the browser window?

```
http://xxxx.xxx/Open.ashx?token=[TOKEN]
```

I'm not a programmer and I know this one is all to simple, but I'm totally lost.

Comment: seems you have to change from  a `GET` to `POST` request, so you can use the input, and not passing the password in an URL !

Comment: Same result, returns a token into the browser, but how to I get that token into the URL?

Comment: what is the expected workflow ? what does the user does before he gets the URL with the token ? can you show your /GetLoginToken.ashx file ?

Comment: The "GetLoginToken.ashx" is not avaiable to me. Basicly it validates whatever password and username it recieves, and if valid, it returns a token. If I manually place that Token in the other URL, it opens a site. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: That's too bad... ok, maybe you can try to make a new file (URL) and use it as an intermediate, so it will catch the user/password send it to the  GetLoginToken.ashx, then grab the return (token) then show it to the user in the URL.